# Why is lotion used as a metaphor for masturbation?

Tags: analysis, sitcoms

I've noticed a theme in sitcoms, more from the 80s/90s than now, that a bottle of hand lotion would be used a sign that a character has been masturbating.

I don't get it. I imagine that lotion might look a bit like semen but I would think that PVC glue would be a better analogue.

How has a lotion (of all things) become a metaphor for masturbating? Why not (say) deodorant?

Comment: Huh? Surely because it's *used* in the act?

Comment: @Walt I think you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I think I'm *getting* you wrong, because I'm lost. But in any case, I strongly advise against the application of glue unless you want to provide an entire ER staff with an epic story.

Comment: Tissues also appear in these innuendoes sometimes, like in the joke [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n94oPxdXfAQ) (around 0:50).

Comment: Yes, tissues I get as a neccessary part of cleaning up, but lotion? Who uses lotion when masturbating?

Comment: Definitely [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2XYMl53eYo).

Comment: Seriously, if you need lotion to masturbate, you might want to see a doctor.

Comment: So the whole question stems from a personal opinion about the necessity of lubricants? Because if it's slippery and safe, people *definitely* use it. Ask around. And no, this isn't necessarily from personal experience but rather common knowledge. Yet I still want this discussion deleted something fierce. ;)

Comment: Fair enough, the side discussion is off-topic for this site. I geninuely had no idea people use lotion for this as I've never found it neccessary.

Comment: Masturbation practices, whether or not they occur in movies or TV shows, really is not an appropriate topic for this stachexchange site.

Comment: @billpg Men who are circumcised need to use lotion, men who still have their foreskin do not.

Comment: @wbogacz till they are on topic , they are appropriate. Other SE have this kind of question http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/697/what-does-hinduism-say-about-masturbation/ it also got mixed reviews but mostly positive.

Comment: @AnkitSharma While I agree that this question might be as on-topic as the question asking why people always cut their wrist in the wrong direction, it is still utterly irrelevant what other sites with entirely different scopes consider on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lotion is not a metaphor for masturbation. It's evidence that the act has transpired, because it's a *tool* used in the act of masturbation. Kleenex is also used in the act.

Comment: People really do that? (This follow-up question is probably off-topic for TV&Movies.)

Comment: People really do that.

Comment: Okay then. Please excuse me while I look for a stack-exchange on sexual practices.

Comment: I would think you only see this in American comedies (since the majority of American men are circumcised and need lotion) and not European comedies (since most European men still have their foreskin and don't need lotion).